# Из-за чего в Dictionary возникает исключение "Элемент с тем же ключом уже был добавлен"?

Tags: c#

Суть такая. `DataGrid` заполняется данными из БД. Все работает хорошо. Исключение появляется когда повторно редактирую одну и ту же строку. Например: В таблице отделов изменяю название отдела - Enter, все хорошо, изменяю повторно - процесс падает с исключением. Трудность (так же и причина) в том, что исключение из внешнего кода как я понял EF библиотеки. Дебажить невозможно. Причину так и не смог понять, что ему не хватает. По выводу видно, что во время исполнения создается некий словарь, куда пишутся пары с редактируемыми из локального контекста объектами. И у меня они пишутся не совсем верно. Заранее спасибо.

DataGrid:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<Subdivision> PrimordialSubdivisions
    {
        get => _primordialSubdivisions;
        set => SetProperty(ref _primordialSubdivisions, value);
    }
....
PrimordialSubdivisions = _appContext.Subdivisions.Local.ToBindingList();
....
subdivisionsGrid.ItemsSource = PrimordialSubdivisions;
```

Обработчик окончания редактирования после которого следует исключение:

```
        private void SubdivisionEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        Subdivision s = (Subdivision)e.Row.Item;
        //Получаем исходный объект из бд с которым будем сравнивать
        var nativeSubdivision = _appContext.GetNativeSubdivision(s);

        if (_changedSubdivisions.ContainsKey(nativeSubdivision))
        {
            //Если при редактировании объект вернули в исходное состояние
            if (_changedSubdivisions[nativeSubdivision].Equals(nativeSubdivision))
            {
                _changedSubdivisions.Remove(nativeSubdivision);
                e.Cancel = true;

                return;
            }

            return;
        }

        if (s.Equals(nativeSubdivision)) return;

        _changedSubdivisions[nativeSubdivision] = s;

        UndoChangesCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

    }
```

Models:

```
public class Worker : ObservableViewModel
{
    protected ILogWriter _innerWriter;

    private string _workerName;
    private string _workerLastName;
    private string _workerOtchestvo;
    private DateTime _workerBirthDate;
    private int _id;
    private Sex _workerSex;

    [Key]
    public int Id {
        get => _id;
        set => SetProperty(ref _id, value);
    }

    public string WorkerName
    {
        get => _workerName;
        set => SetProperty(ref _workerName, value);
    }

    public string WorkerLastName
    {
        get => _workerLastName;
        set => SetProperty(ref _workerLastName, value);
    }

    public string WorkerOtchestvo
    {
        get => _workerOtchestvo;
        set => SetProperty(ref _workerOtchestvo, value);
    }

    public DateTime WorkerBirthDate
    {
        get => _workerBirthDate;
        set => SetProperty(ref _workerBirthDate, value);
    }

    public Sex WorkerSex
    {
        get => _workerSex;
        set => SetProperty(ref _workerSex, value);
    }

    [Column("WorkerSubdivision")]
    public int? WorkerSubdivision { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("WorkerSubdivision")]
    public virtual Subdivision Subdivision { get; set; }

    public Worker() { }

    public Worker(Subdivision subdivision, string name, string lastName, string otchestvo, DateTime birthDate, Sex workerSex)
    {
        Subdivision = GuardWithLog.GuardForNull(subdivision, "Subdivision");
        WorkerName = GuardWithLog.GuardForNull(name, "name");
        WorkerLastName = GuardWithLog.GuardForNull(lastName, "lastName");
        WorkerOtchestvo = GuardWithLog.GuardForNull(otchestvo, "otchestvo");
        WorkerBirthDate = GuardWithLog.GuardForNull(birthDate, "birthDate");
        WorkerSex = GuardWithLog.GuardForNull(workerSex, "worerSex");

        _innerWriter = AsyncLogWriter.CreateInstance();

        _innerWriter.WriteInLog(LogLevel.Information, typeof(Worker), $"Worker {WorkerName} {WorkerLastName} was created");
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var item = obj as Worker;
        if (item == null) return false;
        return Id.Equals(item.Id) && WorkerBirthDate.Equals(item.WorkerBirthDate)
               && WorkerLastName.Equals(item.WorkerLastName) && WorkerName.Equals(item.WorkerName) &&
               WorkerOtchestvo.Equals(item.WorkerOtchestvo)
               && WorkerSex.Equals(item.WorkerSex);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{WorkerLastName} {WorkerName} {WorkerOtchestvo}";
    }
}

    public class Subdivision : ObservableViewModel, IEquatable<Subdivision>
{
    ILogWriter _innerWriter;
    
    private string _subdivName;
    private int _id;
    [Key]
    public int Id { get => _id; set => SetProperty(ref _id, value); }

    public string SubdivisionName
    {
        get => _subdivName; set => SetProperty(ref _subdivName, value);
    }

    [Column("HeadWorker")]
    public int? HeadWorker { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HeadWorker")]
    public virtual Worker Head { get; set; }

    public Subdivision() { }

    private Subdivision(string subdivisionName, Worker headWorker)
    {
        SubdivisionName = GuardWithLog.GuardForNull(subdivisionName, "name");
        Head = GuardWithLog.GuardForNull(headWorker, "headWorker");

        _innerWriter = AsyncLogWriter.CreateInstance();

        _innerWriter.WriteInLog(LogLevel.Information, typeof(Subdivision),
            $"Subdivision {subdivisionName} was created.");
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return SubdivisionName;
    }


    //public static Subdivision CreateInstance(string subdivisionName, Worker headWorker)
    //{
    //    return new Subdivision(subdivisionName, headWorker);
    //}
    public bool Equals(Subdivision other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return _subdivName == other._subdivName && _id == other._id && HeadWorker == other.HeadWorker && Equals(Head, other.Head);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Subdivision) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = (_subdivName != null ? _subdivName.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ _id;
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ HeadWorker.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (Head != null ? Head.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Необработанное исключение</Description><AppDomain>FunnyWaterCarrier.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.ArgumentException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Элемент с тем же ключом уже был добавлен.</Message><StackTrace>   в System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   в System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   в System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2..ctor(IDictionary`2 dictionary, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   в System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.InternalSelectedItemsStorage..ctor(InternalSelectedItemsStorage collection, IEqualityComparer`1 equalityComparer)
```

Итоговый вариант метода после нахождение решения вопроса:

```
private void SubdivisionEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        Subdivision editableItem = (Subdivision)e.Row.Item;

        //Получаем исходный объект из бд с которым будем сравнивать
        var nativeSubdivision = _appContext.GetNativeSubdivision(editableItem);

        if (_changedSubdivisions.ContainsKey(nativeSubdivision.Id))
        {
            //Если при редактировании объект вернули в исходное состояние
            if (_changedSubdivisions[nativeSubdivision.Id].Equals(nativeSubdivision))
            {
                _changedSubdivisions.Remove(nativeSubdivision.Id);
                return;
            }
            return;
        }
        if (editableItem.Equals(nativeSubdivision)) return;
        _changedSubdivisions[nativeSubdivision.Id] = editableItem;
        UndoChangesCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
```

Работает в совокупности с кодом из ответа.

Comment: Как обычно, только выложив вопрос, нашел причину проблемы. Убрав просто из модели отделов реализацию IEqutable исключение перестало возникать. Надо понять, как сохранить реализацию методов сравнения, при этом не допустив данного исключения. Как только точнее вникну в решение, отвечу на свой же вопрос.

Comment: Я же вам говорил убрать `GetHashCode`, попробуйте его убрать, а не `IEquatable`, потому что ваша реализация `GetHashCode` может вообще непредсказуемым образом совпасть у совершенно разных объектов, имеющих разные данные. Хоть и с незначительной вероятностью.

Comment: И снова здравствуйте). Вчера уже смекнул, что дело не в моих методах со словарями (когда уже просто все удалил, а исключение осталось). Про GetHashCode(), у меня изначально его не было а исключение уже возникало. Был переписан только Equals, так как он был нужен для сравнения в моем обработчике. Попробую сейчас оставить его снова без GetHashCode() и посмотреть что будет. Видимо Equals() который нужен мне, ломал исполнение EF.

Comment: Я вижу ошибку у вас в коде в вопросе

Comment: `public class Subdivision : ObservableViewModel, IEquatable<Subdivision>` - есть реализация `public class Worker : ObservableViewModel` - нет реализации. Следовательно словарь никак не сравнивал вам воркеров.

Comment: `Equals(Head, other.Head)`???? `Head.Equals(other.Head)`! Странно, что вы StackOverflowException не словили видимо за счет проверки на `null` только удалось объехать.

Comment: А в чем проблема? Сравнение главы отдела. Или вы про то, что там вертелась бы проверка что Equals отдела включает Equals сотрудника, который в свою очередь включает Equals отдела? Я это предусмотрел. В Equals сотрудника нет сравнения отделов.

Comment: У сотрудника сейчас как раз реализую и у заказов. Вчера только для отдела просто для реализации использовал интерфейс. Сейчас все в порядок привожу, как вы сказали.

Comment: "Смешались в кучу кони, люди..." Если судить по заголовку, исключение выбрасывает Entity Framework. Между тем в конце своего вопроса вы приводите текст ошибки, в котором явно сказано, что исключение выбрасывает Dictionary. | И всё это приправлено wpf, xaml и sql.

Comment: Да, смешались. Сперва не смог сразу понять в чем конкретно дело и сетовал на несколько вещей, т.к. изначально были проблемы с построением связей в БД. Подумал, что может это как то влияет еще. Поправил вопрос.

Comment: `_changedSubdivisions` - это и есть словарь? Но ведь его создали вы! Явно! Это не какой-то внутренний словарь EntityFramework'а. Так зачем приплетать всё лишнее? В словаре есть ключи и значения. Ключи должны быть уникальными. Всё! Осталось найти место, где добавляется значение с таким же ключом.

Comment: Да ладно?) Было бы так все просто) Уж если б в этом была бы проблема вопросов не возникло (как минимум сюда обращенных). Словарь то есть, но он в библиотеке EF, которым он и рулит сам. И по какой причине там оказывались одинаковые ключи, извините батенька, я не уполномочен в таких делах. И вроде все это я описал в вопросе. Так же что ошибка оставалась когда мой словарь даже инициализирован небыл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка связана с тем, что вы пытаете добавить в базу то, что там уже есть. Скорее всего проблема в формировании набора данных для записи. Словарь `Dictionary` думает, что вы пытаетесь в него воткнуть данные с ключом, который там уже есть.

Насколько я знаком с вашим вопросом, вы используете в качестве ключа ссылочный тип. Используйте значимый или немутабельный. Мутабельные типы нельзя использовать в качестве ключа.

Давайте уберем `GetHashCode` и поправим `Equals` и перегрузим операторы `==` и `!=`

```cs
public class Subdivision : ObservableViewModel, IEquatable<Subdivision>
{
    // ...

    public bool Equals(Subdivision? other)
    {
        return other is Subdivision division
               && (ReferenceEquals(this, division)
               || (_subdivName == division._subdivName
               && _id == division._id
               && HeadWorker == division.HeadWorker
               && Head == division.Head));
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Subdivision left, Subdivision right)
        => left.Equals(right);

    public static bool operator !=(Subdivision left, Subdivision right)
        => !left.Equals(right);
}

// здесь вы забыли добавить IEquatable<Worker>
public class Worker : ObservableViewModel, IEquatable<Worker>
{
    // ...

    public bool Equals(Worker? other)
    {
        return other is Worker worker
               && (ReferenceEquals(this, worker)
               || (Id == worker.Id
               && WorkerBirthDate == worker.WorkerBirthDate
               && WorkerLastName == worker.WorkerLastName
               && WorkerName == worker.WorkerName
               && WorkerOtchestvo == worker.WorkerOtchestvo
               && WorkerSex == worker.WorkerSex));
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Worker left, Worker right)
        => left.Equals(right);

    public static bool operator !=(Worker left, Worker right)
        => !left.Equals(right);
}
```

Всё, теперь у вас сравнение идет по содержимому, и если возникает исключение, значит вы пытаетесь добавить в словарь то, что уже там есть.

Comment: Сейчас как раз привел к такому виду. Исключения нет. Но теперь почему то  ContainsKey() не срабатывает. В словаре лежит исходный отдел/редактированный отдел. Аргументом передаю тот же исходный отдел, возвращает false

Comment: @АртёмЕнин `IEquatable<Subdivision>` в оба класса вернули? Сейчас попробую узнать, в чем там дело.

Comment: Извините. Не заметил, что для сотрудника нужен параметр типа как отдел для интерфейса. А кстати почему нужен он?

Comment: @АртёмЕнин Я ошибся в типе для интерфейса, исправил. Перегрузить операторы забыли, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Да, была мысля еще вчера их перегрузить, но потом реализовал через Equals чисто

Comment: @АртёмЕнин я пишу на коленке, там вроде `Worker?` требует `IEquatable<Worker>` как аргумент, верно? Сейчас перепишу ответ...Готово.

Comment: override требует именно object в аргументы. Ругается что нет метода такого для переписывания с аргументом Worker?

Comment: @АртёмЕнин а, я понял, это переопределение метода типа `object`, ну тогда конечно убрать `override`. Убрал.

Comment: То есть переписывание метода базового класса нам вообще не нужно?

Comment: @АртёмЕнин я пока не уверен, смотрю исходники `Dictionary`.

Comment: @АртёмЕнин покопался, нашел, что при условии что `IEquatable<T>` указан, то не требуется переопределение `Equals(obj)`. Можете проверять.

Comment: Спасибо, понял. Сейчас дописал все (еще для заказов дописал). Сейчас проверю

Comment: По прежнему ContainsKey не срабатывает. Попробую через TryGetValue. Не сработало.

Comment: @АртёмЕнин доберусь до компа, гляну еще чего там словарю не хватает, чуть позже. Но вообще должно работать, либо я что-то упустил.

Comment: Да я сам немного озадачен. С моим изначальным кодом ContainsKey работал, но было исключение. Теперь исключения нет, но не работает метод...Нашел ответ на англоязычном SO, пишут, что надо GetHashCode...

Comment: @АртёмЕнин в общем, я еще раз покопался, и нашел, что словарь все-таки юзает `GetHashCode`, а еще я понял, что мутабельный класс не подходит для словаря в качестве ключа. И вся эта история с `IEquatable` что я тут задумал, ни к чему хорошему не приведет. Ключ у словаря должен быть немутабельным, иначе получится ситуация, когда вы добавили класс в качестве ключа, потом его изменили и получили 2 одинаковых ключа, ну по условию `Equals`. Возможность такого эффекта - признак плохой практики. Ключ должен быть простой, либо строка, либо число либо другой значимый или немутабельный тип.

Comment: @АртёмЕнин Вы можете сделать `Dictionary<int, Subdivision>` и использовать в качестве ключа не экземпляр а например `Subdivision.Id`? Тогда то что мы понаписали перестанет влиять на словарь, но может вам пригодиться в другом коде.

Comment: Это гениальное решение) Думаю сработает. А вот по поводу "когда вы добавили класс в качестве ключа, потом его изменили и получили 2 одинаковых ключа, ну по условию Equals"...немного не понял. Изменили - получили два одинаковых...В ключ то я ложу вытянутый из базы и записанный в var объект. Меняю то другой, который лежит в коллекции для источника данных

Comment: @АртёмЕнин ну тогда если вопрос был в том чтобы починить сранивание по содержимому, то мы его починили. Можете принять тогда ответ и пробовать побороть ключи. Других идей, к сожалению, у меня нет. Дополнил предисловие в ответе.

Comment: В предисловии вы верно указали, что у EF есть свой словарь, в который он кладет затронутые объекты по какому то своему алгоритму (что я и предполагал еще в вопросе)). Это все ломало. Переделал на <int, Subdivision> и все прекрасно работает. И Equals() по прежнему пригождается в сравнении для удаления записи, если одинаковы объекты. Спасибо, вопрос закрыт)

Comment: @АртёмЕнин - _Переделал на <int, Subdivision> и все прекрасно работает_ - в каком именно месте вы это сделали? Покажите код.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1262974/373567

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov дополнил вопрос итоговым вариантом метода. При всем уважении, вы даете советы (ответы) не прочитав даже код прикрепленный (это я про вчерашний вопрос закрытый), там явно есть строка с проверкой ключа, вы пишите чтоб я проверил...